# Making requests to another App Engine app

Tags: java, google-app-engine

From my GAE server side code, Iam using urlfetchservice to update the datastore on another GAE. This results in Response code 302

Please find the code snippet below,

```
    String urlVal = "https://valeo-is-qc-dev.appspot.com/a/qccards/"+modelObj.getQc_reference_id()+"/updatellcreference?llcref="+modelObj.getReference()+"&llcrefid="+modelObj.getId();
    URL url = new URL(urlVal);
    // Create HTTPRequest and set headers
    com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions fetchOptions = com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults();
    fetchOptions.doNotValidateCertificate();
    fetchOptions.doNotFollowRedirects();
    HTTPRequest httpRequest = null;
    httpRequest = new HTTPRequest(new URL(url.toString()), HTTPMethod.PUT,fetchOptions);
    httpRequest.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + token_id));
    httpRequest.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid", "valeo-is-llc-dev"));
    httpRequest.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("Host", "https://test-is-abc-dev.appspot.com"));
    httpRequest.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain"));

    URLFetchService fetcher = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
    HTTPResponse httpResponse = null;
    httpResponse = fetcher.fetch(httpRequest);
    if (httpResponse.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "abc def Bridge Response OK --- " + httpResponse.getResponseCode());
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "abc def Bridge Response OK --- " + httpResponse.toString());
    } else {
        // Server returned HTTP error code.
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "abc def Bridge Response FAIL --- " + httpResponse.getResponseCode());
    }
```

Comment: what is the question btw? (ps, there is error in your code. responseCode != 200 doesn't mean error. 302 is redirect code, that perfectly fine. only 400+ codes are error codes)

Comment: PUT is not working. Since it is redireting to 302, the update is not hapening in the destination GAE. It is redirecting to the servicelogin url of the destination GAE.

Comment: are you sure? usually 302 follows successful PUT/POST. anyway, if it redirects to auth, then it's not because PUT is not working, but because you're not authenticated

Comment: You are correct. There is no problem with the PUT. The problem is, my destination GAE2, is not authenticating me , in order to execute the PUT.

My src GAE : https://vG-is-llc-dev.appspot.com
My destination GAE : https://vG-is-qc-dev.appspot.com

These are 2 different Google App Engines running. Both have the same users.

From GAE1 iam sending my authToken as below,
httpRequest.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + token_id));

But this is not getting authenticated in the GAE2

Comment: so I think you have to ask a different question, about how to authenticate and where to get correct oauth token

Comment: Yea Correct. I want to get authenticated in the GAE2 from GAE1. I have service account credentials for both.